# cypher - filter an array based on another array

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have one node which has two properties. Each property is an array. For example:

```
MATCH (n:myNode)
RETURN n.prop1, n.prop2

//this returns

prop1                prop2
[X, Y, X]            [A, B, C]
```

How would I select the values in prop2 where prop1 == X, giving this result:

```
[A, C]
```

I have tried something like the following, but clearly I'm missing something:

```
MATCH (n:myNode)
RETURN FILTER(i in n.prop2 WHERE n.prop1='X')
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (n:myNode)
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], i in RANGE(0, SIZE(n.prop1)-1) |
  CASE n.prop1[i] WHEN 'X' THEN s + n.prop2[i] ELSE s END) AS result;
```

Comment: Great! This helped a lot. Thank you.